# Desktop Excel hangs when the getSelectedRanges method is called in a workbook where a big range is selected

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am trying to develop an Excel JavaScript add-in that processes all selected ranges.

When selecting a large range with data, such as A1:O1000000, desktop **Excel hangs** when I call the ctx.sync method after getting the **ctx.workbook.getSelectedRanges()** object.

Also the problem is reproduced in Excel 2016 and Excel 2019 desktop versions.
In Excel Online (web), this code works normally.

My Excel version is 16.0.12430.20172 64-bit

```
onTestClick(e)
    {
        console.log("onTestClick");
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            let selectedRanges = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRanges();

            selectedRanges.load(["areas", "areaCount", "address", "addressLocal"]); 
            selectedRanges.areas.load({ $all: false, address: true,  addressLocal: true}); 

            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                for (let index = 0; index < selectedRanges.areaCount; index++) {
                    let area = selectedRanges.areas.items[index];
                    console.log("area[" + index + "] = " + area.address);
                }

            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("onTestClick sync error: " + error);
            }).then(()=>{
                console.log("onTestClick end");
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("onTestClick Excel.run error: " + error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Fedor, I can repro this issue, and I have created a bug 3955509 to track this issue, our team will investigate this issue and we will keep you updated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script above, load "areas" in selectedRanges is not necessary.  You can make some changes on "selectedRanges.load(["areas", "areaCount", "address", "addressLocal"]);" to "selectedRanges.load(["areaCount", "address", "addressLocal"]);" instead. With the change, you can see the result is returned quickly.

The reason is that "areas" is Excel.RangeCollection(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangecollection?view=excel-js-preview), which returns a collection of rectangular ranges that comprise this RangeAreas object. The return value for Range(A1:O1000000) is too big to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

When calling selectedRanges.load("areas"), it equals to call selectedRanges.areas.load() which is a empty load. An empty-load loads all scalar properties which can have significant performance overhead.

references: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/performance#load-necessary-properties-only
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-advanced-concepts#scalar-and-navigation-properties